# Override Width Styling of Content To Fit Max Width of Parent Table

Tags: css

I have embedded something with its own CSS into a table.

```
<table width="250px">
<tr>
<td width="10%"></td>
<td width="80%">
<!-- embedded content here -->
</td>
<td width="10%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The embedded object has its own CSS with a width of 300px.

As you can see my table is only 250px and it stretches the table out - distorting the page.

Is there any way I can set max-width on the table itself to override this CSS or do it another way, perhaps with `<div>` ?

Comment: Why does the embedded object have a width of 300px?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, it is the default size for the object. I can change it, but wanted to know if there is a way around it to prevent my page becoming distorted.

Comment: What HTML element is the content?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the embedded content but if it simple text you should use `word-break:break-all` on it.